# Facebook PHP SDK getSession method always NULL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk

I'm really confused about the Facebook session related methods. Everything besides the ->API method in which you have to supply an access token now seems to rely on getSession returning whatever is expected to be in a valid session (I know access token is one of those things).

My code performs the oAuth handshake and gets a valid access token which I store to $params['access_token'] and then can call the method ->api(/me, $params['access_token']) to get data back.

How do I set a valid session to the FB object so that I can use the other methods, such as ->getLogoutURL? I know there is a ->setSession method but I don't know what it is expecting as input.

Hopefully my question is clear...
1. I can get a valid access token
2. How do I make the ->getSession method return anything other than NULL?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this same problem and after going through many forums, I came up with this.
getSession() always returns a null the first time it is accessed.

The way that i proceed is, i make a login request, no matter the current status of the user and from the session object that is returned, i save it as a Session Variable, using PHP.

Later based on this session variable, you can validate a user and destroy this session when a user logs out
hope this info helps

Comment: I could never get it to return data. I ended up just writing my own implementations since barely anything in the PHP SDK worked.